# SVG rectangle's stroke widths are cut off on top/left. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, svg

My SVG's strokes are somehow cut off when I have a large stroke width for my rectangle. I have the following code:

```
<svg width="500px" height="300px">
    <rect width="352" height="128" stroke="#333" stroke-width="16" fill-opacity="0"/>
</svg>
```

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ej6fzbg/3/

As you can see from the jsfiddle, the stroke widths are cut slightly for the top and left sides of the rectangle. How do I fix this such that the stroke widths are 16 pixels across the entire rectangle?

I believe I can change the x and y positions of the rectangle, but I believe that wouldn't be very robust if I wanted to change the stroke width later on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the rect strokes are centered on the boundary of the rectangle, either use half the stroke width every time (8 in this case) for X and Y:

```
<svg width="500px" height="300px">
    <rect x="8" y="8" width="352" height="128" stroke="#333" stroke-width="16" fill-opacity="0"/>
</svg>
```

or offset the viewbox of the SVG by half the stroke width:

```
<svg width="500px" height="300px" viewbox="-8 -8 492 292">
    <rect width="352" height="128" stroke="#333" stroke-width="16" fill-opacity="0"/>
</svg>
```